# How can I ask: please check the php

Tags: php

According to this meaning..Check whether this is correct or not.

method below will return all records from the Contact table in the database.  Write code to call this method and display the results (all three columns for all records) in a html table with appropriate column headings.

[image]

Comment: what is wrong with this code. ? It seems like working correctly

Comment: In the future, instead of images, we much prefer **formatted** text in the question body, or links to a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: Im going to hazard a guess that the final td in your echo is breaking layout. It should be a closing table row. **</tr>**

Answer (score 2):

Your header row does not end with `</tr>`

Your content row does not end with `</tr>`

Change the ends of those lines from `<tr>` and `<td>` respectively,  to `</tr>`

Remember to add the `</table>` after the loop!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
$result=getContact();
?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>Adress</th>
    <th>Zip</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($result as $person){
    ?>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo $person['LastName']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $person['Address']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $person['Zip']; ?></td>
     </tr>
    <?php
    } 
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned reasons are correct. This code would fix your errors:

```
<?php

$html = "
  <table>
   <thead>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>Adress</th>
    <th>Zip</th>
   </thead>
  <tbody>";
echo $html;

    $result=getContact();
    foreach($result as $person) {
      $html = "
       <tr>
       <td>".$person['LastName']."</td>
       <td>".$person['Address']."</td>
       <td>".$person['Zip']."</td>
       </tr>";
      echo $html;
    } 

    $html = "
  </tbody>
</table>";
echo $html;
```